# A Gallery which uses Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to make a gallery with `Glide` at android platform. But i stucked at something. I have a `JSONArray` for my gallery which contains image links. But i cant use `glide` with those links. Any suggestions ? How can i list them or display them? But first of all, how can i show these images as a list ?

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        List<GalleryDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] Photos= new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            GalleryDetails g = new GalleryDetails();
            g.Photos= jsonObject.getString("Photos");
            gorsel.add(g);
            Photos[i] = g.Photos;
        }

        Glide.with(context).load(Photos); ??? IDK THIS ONE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add this line,

```
Glide.with(context).load(Photos[i]).into(your_imageview);
```

Inside this:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    List<GalleryDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] Photos= new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        GalleryDetails g = new GalleryDetails();
        g.Photos= jsonObject.getString("Photos");
        gorsel.add(g);
        Photos[i] = g.Photos;
        .........(Add Here)
    }
```

Try it, Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for that, but first of all, i'm trying to show them as a image list. I cant figure out how.

Comment: You mean one below the other? also, paste your xml code so that I can suggest something. @Kuroiteiken

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this `Photos[i]` in your glide.

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        List<GalleryDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] Photos= new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            GalleryDetails g = new GalleryDetails();
            g.Photos= jsonObject.getString("Photos");
            gorsel.add(g);
            Photos[i] = g.Photos;
        }

  Glide.with(ctx).load(Photos.get(i).toString()‌​ 
  ).into(your_imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        List<GalleryDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        //String[] Photos= new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            GalleryDetails g = new GalleryDetails();
            g.Photos= jsonObject.getString("Photos");
            gorsel.add(g);
            //Photos[i] = g.Photos;

            Glide.with(context).load(g.Photos).into(imageView);
        }
```